# Add an existing div element with classes (along with its underlying elements) to a div

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I need to have a function that would add an existing div with a class (along with its underlying elements) to a particular div using for loop. It looks like this:

```
<div class="left-col">
    <div class="list-row">
        <div class="list-row2">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to loop through a function that will produce or duplicate "list-row" twice.

```
$(function() {
    var leftcol = document.getElementsByClassName('left-col');

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var listrow = document.querySelector('.list-row');
        leftcol.appendChild(listrow[i]);
    }
})
```

It should look like this:

```
<div class="left-col">
    <div class="list-row">
        <div class="list-row2">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-row">
        <div class="list-row2">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="list-row">
        <div class="list-row2">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and set the `deep` property to `true`. This will clone the node and all of its descendants.

For example:

```js
function cloneNode(copies = 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < copies; i++) {
    let leftcol = document.getElementsByClassName('left-col')[0];
    let nodeToClone = document.querySelector(".list-row");
    let clonedNode = nodeToClone.cloneNode(true);
    leftcol.appendChild(clonedNode);
  }
}

clone.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cloneNode();
});
```

```html
<button id="clone" type="button">Clone Node</button>
<div class="left-col">
  <div class="list-row">Test</div>
</div>
```

If you wanted to insert more than one copy, you could pass a different value to the `cloneNode` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following way:

```js
$(function() {
    var leftcol = document.querySelector('.left-col');
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var listrow = document.querySelector('.list-row').cloneNode();
      listrow.textContent = i + 1 + listrow.textContent;
      leftcol.appendChild(listrow);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-col">
    <div class="list-row">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to copy the entire content of an element to another element. The boolean argument passed to the `clone` function determines whether the events associated with the cloned element has to be copied or not. `true` indicates all the events associated with that div has to be copied.

```js
$(function() {
$('.list-row').each(function(){
$(".left-col").append($(this).clone(true));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-col">
    <div class="list-row"><h1>This is original row</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    var leftcol = document.getElementsByClassName('left-col');
    var listrow = document.querySelector('.list-row');

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        leftcol.appendChild(listrow.clone(true));
    }
})
```